# За какое минимальное количество тестов, можно протестировать 10 булевых переменных?

Tags: логика

На собеседовании задали вопрос:

> За какое минимальное количество тестов, можно протестировать 10 буленовских переменных и почему?

Как вы понимаете ответ 10 и х-1 (если вдруг они связаны) оказался не верным(

Comment: а что означает в данном случае "протестировать"?

Comment: Как я понял, получить от них true/false

Comment: Ну вот будет вам наука - сначала уточнять, что имеется в виду, а потом думать над ответом. Я на 100% уверен, что там не "получить от них тру/фалс" (это совсем не протестировать). Протестировать означает сравнить желаемое поведение/значение с полученным. И прежде чем "тестировать" нужно узнать что в данном случае "желаемое".

Comment: Наверное смысл задачи в том, чтобы узнать какое значение у всех 10 переменных за минимальное кол-во тестов. При этом наверняка можно пользоваться только и/или/xor

Comment: @CrazyElf даа...

Comment: Но как я понимаю ответ от этого не сильно изменится

Answer (score 6):

Один тест.

Т.к. непонятно, что в данном случае означает "протестировать" и все остальные вводные данные неизвестны, то все необходимое придумал себе сам:

нужно протестировать, что каждая из 10 переменных равна определенному значению.

Минимальное количество тестов для  10 (и любого количества до 64) переменных - один.

Собираем все эти 10 битов в одну переменную по типу `0b 0000 00ab cdef ghij` и накладываем маску с контрольными значениями. По результату будет понятно, какие переменные соответствуют требованиям, а какие нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем кому интересно, ответ был ((10в10степени)*2)-2. Идея была в том, что нет никаких тестовых данных, а есть просто "положение выключателей" и они могут быть в произвольных позициях и могут быть связаны между собой. Короче это было больше про вариативную математику, а не про программирование(